# Winbind group lookup painfully slow

Tags: linux, samba, active-directory, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am running winbind on an RHEL 6 system. Everything works fine except group lookups, so many commands (including `sudo`) are painfully slow. I did an `strace` which shows that winbind looks up every group and every user within each group for the current user. Some of these groups have 20000+ users so a simple `sudo` can take 60 seconds to complete.

I really only care about speeding up the sudo command. Ideal solutions would make it so either:

1. groups with more than X number of users will not be looked up, or
2. sudo bypasses group lookups altogether.

Here is my current "smb.conf" for *winbind*:

```
workgroup = EXAMPLE
password server = AD1.EXAMPLE.ORG
realm = EXAMPLE.ORG
security = ads
idmap uid = 10000-19999
idmap gid = 10000-19999
idmap config EXAMPLE:backend = rid
idmap config EXAMPLE:range = 10000000-19999999
winbind enum users = no
winbind enum groups = no
winbind separator = +
template homedir = /home/%U
template shell = /bin/bash
winbind use default domain = yes
winbind offline logon = false
```

Comment: `wbinfo -g` is flow for you? The fact that command executions are slow has nothing to do with winbind. You have disabled `winbind enum groups` which speeds up login.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It's not group lookup that is slow, it is enumerating the users within AD groups that have 20000+ users. Since sudo does a group lookup on the user, it looks through every single user within each group that user is a member of to find nested groups. The same behavior can be seen from the `groups` command. It takes forever since most users are members of groups that have thousands of users.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem after upgrading sudo and found out from Red Hat that sudo changed its group membership resolution algorithm when going from sudo-1.7.4p5-13.el6_3.x86_64 to sudo-1.8.6p3-7.el6.x86_64. In sudo-1.7.4, group membership was resolved for all groups listed in /etc/sudoers and if the username was found in the list, it was granted sudo privileges. In sudo-1.8.6, this was changed to be the other way around - sudo fetched a list of groups that the user is a member of, then checked if any of those groups were listed in sudoers.

This results in getgrgid() for every group the user is a member of, so if some groups are large, this will be quite slow.  You can either downgrade sudo or put the large groups as empty groups in your local /etc/group file so that AD is not contacted for them (assuming the large groups aren't referenced by the Linux system for any access control).

Comment: This is good to know. I can't see downgrading sudo as a possibility but do let me know if you find a way to reconfigure sudo to go back to the old method.

Comment: In the most recent version it states the following: "Sudo will look up all of a user's groups by group ID and use the resulting group names when matching sudoers entries. If there are multiple groups with the same ID, the group name returned by the system getgrgid() library function is the name that will be used when matching sudoers entries." I doubt they will change it back.

Answer (score 1):

The old method (i.e. 1.7.x) can be reverted by group plugins:

```
Defaults group_plugin="system_group.so"
```

Alternatively just force to use `/etc/group` only (no winbind lookups etc.):

```
Defaults group_plugin="group_file.so /etc/group"
```

Comment: This seems promising. However, my libexec does not contain those plugins you mention (neither system_group.so nor group_file.so). What plugin should I install/use?

Comment: @Marty What distro are you using? Also they are in `/usr/lib/sudo` not `/usr/libexec/sudo`, at least on Gentoo.

Comment: I decided to just download the source for sudo and compile the plugins.  I tried both plugins and neither change the slow sudo lookup. It seems to do the group lookup before the Defaults are even read.

Answer (score 0):

disable nested groups
`winbind nested groups = false`

Comment: Why is this a good thing to do?

Comment: I need nested groups to work...

Answer (score -2):

or just add "winbind expand groups = 0" to your /etc/samba/smb.cnf file (then switch to local root account and "/etc/init.d/winbind stop; /etc/init.d/samba restart; /etc/init.d/winbind start")

first sudo after a reboot might take a moment (but won't be molasses like you are experiencing), and for sure, subsequent will be as expected (fast); for anyone else, you might just use a local admin account for sudo commands (as you are forced to create one local account, yes?)

Comment: Answers should, as much as possible, stand alone. Please don't write sentence fragments, and, if you're referring to another answer, say which one. (Different users see the answers in different orders, so don't refer to "the above answer".)

Comment: sorry about that (I am cryptic), was replying to op's **I really only care about speeding up the sudo command**; this will definitely speed up sudo (the line added to smb.cnf), but then you cannot get answers to "getent group NAMEHERE"; so, if you need that _and_ want fast sudo, my second suggestion was to switch to a local account to do sudo stuff